# How to upload via FTP (or alt.) to AWS S3?

Tags: backup, ftp, amazon-s3, upload, amazon-web-services

A simple question about Amazon (AWS) S3 storage. Is there any other way to upload data to S3 apart from the web console interface?

I have a huge amount of family photos and home videos split into hundreds of directories I would like to backup remotely, so FTP seemed as the most convenient option in this case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing many options I finally went for the free Windows client of [CrossFTP](http://www.crossftp.com/) which so far works great uploading entire directories to Amazon S3 just like any other FTP session.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Minio client aka mc](https://github.com/minio/mc) Its open source, single binary & compatible with AWS S3. The client is available for Windows, Linux, Mac, FreeBSD.

You could run `mc mirror` for performing the same.

Mirror a local folder recursively to Amazon S3 cloud storage.

```
  $ mc mirror C:\backup\2014 s3\documents\2014\
```

You can also check [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnWYd9f4il3tyshx5M9lrGw) videos we have added explaining the operation, hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://www.minio.io)